# Почему Beautifulsoup находит не все теги 'tr'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

На странице есть 14 тегов  но **Beautifulsoup** находит несколько штук, при этом не по порядку, сильно разбросано. Еще, каким то магическим образом, он берет теги со следующей страницы, хотя у него нет сыллки на нее.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#function for receive html
def get_html(url):
    response = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    return urlopen(response).read()

#for parsing
def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    table = soup.find('table', class_='table table-normal project-list')
    projects = []
    for row in  table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        projects.append({
            'Title: ': cols[0].a.text,
            'Category: ': [category.text for category in cols[0].div.find_all('small')],
            'Price: ': cols[1].text.strip()
        })

    for project in projects:
        print(project)
        print()



def main():
    parse(get_html('https://freelancehunt.com/projects?skills[]=22'))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: У меня ваш код работает корректно, возвращает все 14 проектов с 1 страницы.

Comment: Он возвращает 14 проектов, но 2 и 3 пропустил, вернул 4 потом снова пропустил. Проверьте соответствуют ли проекты на сайте, с теми что выводит скрипт.

Comment: Похоже соответствуют https://imgur.com/a/JlE1piK

Comment: Нет, у вас так же не соответствуют. После "Создания модуля Скрапер-парсер" должен идти "Автоматизация запросов к WA и скрапинг ", а скрипт выдает "Web Scraping сайта".

Comment: я тока что зашел туда по ссылке  - Web Scraping сайта :))

Comment: То же самое я вижу и на странице https://imgur.com/a/LHzh09j Возможно вы залогинились на сайте и он вам показывает посты, которые не видят неавторизованные пользователи?

Comment: Вот как у меня отображается эта страница https://imgur.com/a/VYagJXY

Comment: вот несколько первых - `Создания модуля Скрапер-парсер 
-Web Scraping сайта 
-
Сделать веб-систему управления agile-проектами.
-
Образовательный метапрофиль пользователя  
-
Требуется Python-дев с опытом взаимодействия с биржами (BitMEX/Binace)`

Comment: @Smooth так вы залогинены на этом сайте или нет? Что видите, если откроете эту страницу в режиме инкогнито?

Comment: @Smooth сейчас увидел, что "Автоматизация запросов к WA и скрапинг" у меня отображается на 2 странице.

Comment: Действительно, даже стыдно стало. А как сделать чтобы парсер заходил как залогиненый пользователь?

Comment: @Smooth как я вижу, во время входа, форма с login и password отправляется на адрес [https://freelancehunt.com/profile/dologin](https://freelancehunt.com/profile/dologin). Я бы попробовал с помощью [requests.Session](https://3.python-requests.org/user/advanced/#session-objects) делать `POST` запрос на этот адрес и дальше уже в этой сессии работать.